# Position center with float left and with, but it's not centered, how?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I want to centered a few blocks, in a row a three next to each other and the row beneath also three blocks in a row. Here is my html and css. AT the moment it is not next to each other in a row. Look at my jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/fop5q28x/4/

```
    <div id="engagement">
    <img src="img/engagement.jpg" alt="engagament" />
    <h2>Engagement</h2>
    <p>Content automatisch doorplaatsen</br>
        naar uw Youtube, Facebook of </br>
        twitter kanaal</p>
    </div>

    <div id="conversie">
        <img src="img/conversie.jpg" alt="conversie" />
        <h2>Conversie</h2>
        <p>Van kijkers naar lid, klant koper of</br>
            actieve deelnemer. Juist niet alleen</br>
            voor grote organisaties</p>
    </div>

    <div id="elearning">
        <img src="img/elearning.jpg" alt="elearning"/>
        <h2>E-learning</h2>
        <p>Online Video is een van de snelst</br>
            groeiende onderwijsmethode aan</br>
            het worden</p>
    </div>  




    <div id="klanttevreden">
        <img src="img/klanttevreden.jpg" alt="klanttevredenheid" />
        <h2>Klanttevredenheid & Call-reductie</h2>
        <p>Doordat klanten online goed worden</br>
            geholpen hoeven zij niet meer</br>
            te bellen of e-mailen</p>
        </div>

        <div id="communicatie">
        <img src="img/communicatie.jpg" at="communicatie" />
        <h2>Corperate Communicatie</h2>
        <p>Cras justo odio, daboitus ac facicilis in,</br>
            egestas eget quam. Vestibulumporta </br>felis euismod semper</p>
        </div>

        <div id="advertentie">
        <img src="img/advertentie.jpg" alt="advertentie" />
        <h2>Advertientie Omzetverhoging</h2>
        <p>Cras justo odio, daboitus ac facicilis in,</br>
            egestas eget quam. Vestibulumporta </br>felis euismod semper</p>
    </div>

   </div>
```

Comment: It is centered, it's just that the text isn't long enough to fill the whole space, try adding   text-align: center; to #bovensterij and you'll see what I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/fop5q28x/1/

Answer (score 2):

`#klanttevreden` isn't floating because you have a syntax error in your css.

```
#klanttevreden,{
    float: left;
    width: 33.3333333%;

}
```

Notice that comma.

[Fiddle courtesy of Suresh Ponnukalai](https://jsfiddle.net/fop5q28x/5/).

Answer (score 1):

Just Use Display:inline-block instead float:left, check updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fop5q28x/3/)

```
div {
    width: 33.3333333%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: Now i have another problem, it is not responsive and it looks like my media queries don't work........do you have a solution. When i scale there are two blocks next to each other.